# PHP in a 404 script to 301?

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I want to 301 a large amount of old URLs.

Can I do this via PHP in a 404 script, or would this mess up search engine results (them thinking the pages are not found)?

My current .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

My 404/index.php script plan:

```
<?
switch (rtrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/")) {
    case "/blah/foo" :
        $redirect="/somewhere_else/";
        break;
    case "/over_here" :
        $redirect="/over_there/";
        break;
    case "/etc/etc/etc" :
        $redirect="/etc/and_so_on/";
        break;
}

if($redirect) {
    header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header ("Location: ".$redirect);
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404: Page not found.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>404: Page not found.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, basically, the redirecting isn't a problem, but I don't want a search engine to think these pages are "not found" or will "think less" of them, or anything like that...

Is this legit? Will Google be happy with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a `Location` HTTP header automatically sets status accordingly. It's [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and it's easy to test with Firebug or your browser's equivalent tool.

Comment: You need to add header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

Comment: @NanheKumar - The whole point of the question is avoiding 404. You can only have one HTTP status and it needs to be 301.

Comment: You are right but you can see above code if $redirect is not set then you are working for 404

Comment: @NanheKumar - Sorry but I can't understand what you mean. The question is IMHO quite clear: use Apache's Not Found handler page to redirect to moved documents when possible. I think it's possible and I've even done it myself for years.

Comment: I just tried this out, using "Fetch as Google" (what a nice tool!). It appears to work nicely!